# Find the coordinates of a point in a given triangle

Tags: analytic-geometry, triangles

I am trying to solve part **iv** of this question. The picture should explain the question. I know the answer is $8$,but have no clue how to arrive at this. 
[image: question]

Comment: Have you tried using distance formula ? What work have you done so far ?

Comment: I have, to find the base length.

Comment: Did you try using the distance formula to find $RQ$ and $RP$ and equated those two together ?

Comment: That makes sense, I'll give it a shot, thanks for the hint

Comment: Indeed you are correct, I just need to get to grips with the maths behind it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point $(x_0,y_0)$ that lies in the middle of the 2 points $P$ and $Q$ is $$(x_0,y_0)=(4,4)$$
You are looking for an isosceles triangle, so that a line from $R$ to the base would be orthogonal to it.

Let the slope $m_1$ be the one corresponding to $QR$ and the slope $m_2$ be that of the middle point and $R$.

Demand $m_1\cdot m_2=-1$:
$$m_1=\frac{6-0}{8-2}=\frac{1}{2}$$and $$m_2=\frac{4-r}{4-2} $$and so you can solve for $r$:$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{4-r}{4-2}=-1$$ to get $$r=8$$

Comment: Wouldn't that just give me coordinates that would make the triangle a right angled one?

Comment: Yes it would. My mistake, I thought you are asking for help in part c. of the exercise. I shall delete my answer, or edit it.

Comment: I appreciate the help though.

Comment: Edited my original answer for the correct part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

$$RQ^2=RP^2\to (2-0)^2+(2-r)^2=(8-2)^2+(6-r)^2\\
8-4r=72-12r\to r=8$$